# integrability condition on a surface

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $v_1$ and $v_2$ be two vector fields on a two-dimensional surface. If I have a PDE on the surface
\begin{align*}
\nabla_{v_1} f(x) &= A(f(x), x)\\
\nabla_{v_2} f(x) &= B(f(x), x)
\end{align*}

where $f$ is an unknown function and $A$ and $B$ are known functions, what is the integrability condition I need to check to guarantee that $f$ (locally) exists? Is it

$$\nabla_{v_1}\nabla_{v_2} f - \nabla_{v_2}\nabla_{v_1} f - \nabla_{[v_1,v_2]}f = 0?$$

Answer (score 1):

It seems this question was asked on mathoverflow, with the answer being "yes": https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115750/are-frobenius-integrability-conditions-covariant